# Azure B2C: How to pass login_hint to GoogleExchange?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I am doing implicit flow for Azure B2C.
I try to do the silent login to obtain new id_token while id_token got expired with GoogleExchange.

If only one google account is logined, that's fine.
However, if multiple google accounts are logined, the page always redirect to google select account screen even I set prompt=none.

I trace the network request, the login_hint, domain_hint and the prompt are not passed from Azure B2C to Google.

I have searched similar question in Stackoverflow.
I am asked to change the technical profile of domain: google.com.
But I didn't find it in the profile I downloaded.

What should I modify to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Here is the profile file

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" TenantObjectId="7a2f1239-4221-468d-860f-3881a3c3edab" PolicyId="B2C_1_signin-email" PublicPolicyUri="http://xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>base-v1</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted1.1">
        <LoadUri>https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/portal/signup_unified.html</LoadUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signinandsignupwithpassword">
        <LoadUri>https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/portal/login_unified.html</LoadUri>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signinandsignupwithpassword.en.rp" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup1.1">
        <LoadUri>https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/portal/web-portal/signup_unified.html</LoadUri>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccountsignup1.1.en.rp" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization Enabled="true">
      <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
        <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
      </SupportedLanguages>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.signinandsignupwithpassword.en.rp">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimsProvider" StringId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange">Email signup</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimsProvider" StringId="GoogleExchange">google</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimsProvider" StringId="FacebookExchange">facebook</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup1.1.en.rp">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="surname" StringId="DisplayName">Last Name</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="surname" StringId="UserHelpText">Your last name (also known as family name or surname).</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="givenName" StringId="DisplayName">First Name</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="givenName" StringId="UserHelpText">Your first name (also known as given name).</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
    </Localization>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-Common">
          <EnabledForUserJourneys>OnClaimsExistence</EnabledForUserJourneys>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">3600</Item>
            <Item Key="id_token_lifetime_secs">3600</Item>
            <Item Key="refresh_token_lifetime_secs">1209600</Item>
            <Item Key="rolling_refresh_token_lifetime_secs">7776000</Item>
            <Item Key="IssuanceClaimPattern">AuthorityAndTenantGuid</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationContextReferenceClaimPattern">None</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Input">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-ReadCommon">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signinandsignupwithpassword">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>
      <SessionExpiryInSeconds>86400</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
      <ContentDefinitionParameters>
        <Parameter Name="ui_locales">{Culture:RFC5646}</Parameter>
      </ContentDefinitionParameters>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="trustFrameworkPolicy" Required="true" DefaultValue="{policy}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: Quick question, Are you seeing the same behavior if you try silent-renew immediately after user login to the application? I mean of same behavior is seeing multiple google accounts to login.

Comment: Yes, it has the same behavior.

Comment: I predict you using basic policies. For basic policies no need to define domain explicitly. You can directly append domain_hint=google.com for your "Run Now" URL, that will directly take you to google login page instead of showing IDP selection page.

Comment: One more quick test regarding **prompt=none**. Try Login with multiple users in Google first and log-out (assume google sign in page shows multiple accounts to sign in). Now copy "Run Now" URL and try login using google IDP, it will show login page with multiple accounts and login with one account. On successful login, again use "Run Now" url on the same browser and update the query param (prompt=login with prompt= none) and see whether it is showing google login page or silently taking you back to redirect URI with id_token.

Comment: The domain_hint works, but It still show the select account page even prompt=none.

Comment: DId you try my 3rd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940631/azure-b2c-how-to-pass-login-hint-to-googleexchange?noredirect=1#comment88882388_50940631 comment? what is the result you see?

Comment: Yes, if I logined multiple account, it redirect to the google and ask me to select account even prompt=none (I found that it does not pass the prompt=none to google).
If I logined only one account in google, it behave correctly and silently taking me back to redirectURI with id_token in fragment.

Comment: I verified from my side and it is working as expected. Are you trying using an application or trying directly from the portal "Run Now" blade? if you using from an application, try using from "Run Now" blade.

Comment: I test it using "Run Now". But it doesn't work as expected. Did you login multiple accounts in google? The select account screen should show at least two accounts without the gray text 'signed out'.